# Fastest and most efficient way to insert and update a lot of rows in cassandra using cqlengine

Tags: python, csv, cassandra, cql

I have a csv file with 15000000 records that I'm trying to process into a cassandra table. Here's an example of the column headers and data:

[image]

To help make more sense of it, here is my model in python:

```
class DIDSummary(Model):
    __keyspace__ = 'processor_api'

    did = columns.Text(required=True, primary_key=True, partition_key=True)
    month = columns.DateTime(required=True, primary_key=True, partition_key=True)
    direction = columns.Text(required=True, primary_key=True)
    duration = columns.Counter(required=True)
    cost = columns.Counter(required=True)
```

Right now I'm trying to process the data in each row of the csv file and insert them in batches of 500, 1000, 10000, 250, etc. but with the same time results (about .33 seconds per 1000, which means it would take 90 minutes to get through all of them). I also tried taking a multiprocessing pool and `apply_async()`'ing each `batch.execute()` call, with no better results. Is there a way I could, in python, use an **SSTableWriter**, or do something else to insert them into cassandra better? For reference, here's my `process_sheet_row()` method:

```
def process_sheet_row(self, row, batch):
    report_datetime = '{0}{1:02d}'.format(self.report.report_year, self.report.report_month)
    duration = int(float(row[self.columns['DURATION']]) * 10)
    cost = int(float(row[self.columns['COST']]) * 100000)

    anisummary = DIDSummary.batch(batch).create(did='{}{}'.format(self.report.ani_country_code, row[self.columns['ANI']]),
                                                direction='from',
                                                month=datetime.datetime.strptime(report_datetime, '%Y%m'))
    anisummary.duration += duration
    anisummary.cost += cost
    anisummary.batch(batch).save()

    destsummary = DIDSummary.batch(batch).create(did='{}{}'.format(self.report.dest_country_code, row[self.columns['DEST']]),
                                                 direction='to',
                                                 month=datetime.datetime.strptime(report_datetime, '%Y%m'))
    destsummary.duration += duration
    destsummary.cost += cost
    destsummary.batch(batch).save()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:** Here is my code for going through the file and processing it:

```
with open(self.path) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    if arr[0] == 'inventory':
            self.parse_inventory(reader)
    b = BatchQuery(batch_type=BatchType.Unlogged)
    i = 1
    for row in reader:
        self.parse_sheet_row(row, b)
        if not i % 1000:
            connection.check_connection() # This just makes sure we're still connected to cassandra. Check code below
            self.pool.apply_async(b.execute())
            b = BatchQuery(batch_type=BatchType.Unlogged)
        i += 1
print "Done processing: {}".format(self.path)
print "Time to Execute: {}".format(datetime.datetime.now() - start)
print "Batches: {}".format(i / 1000)
print "Records processed: {}".format(i - 1)
```

And just because this might be a bit of help, here's the `connection.check_connection()` method (and surrounding methods):

```
def setup_defaults():
    connection.setup(['127.0.0.1'], 'processor_api', lazy_connect=True)

def check_connection():
    from cdr.models import DIDSummary
    try:
        DIDSummary.objects.all().count()
    except CQLEngineException:
        setup_defaults()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batches, in general, aren't the fastest method for performing insertions. Especially so in your unlogged batches containing various partitions. Some reading on batches [here](https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword-40f00e35e23e)

If you can pull away from cqlengine for insertion, you should try [async callback chaining](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/performance.html?#callback-chaining-callback-full-pipeline-py) which is implemented in the Python driver under: [cassandra.execute_concurrent](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/concurrent.html).

I've had major improvements in inserts/sec moving to this method after misusing batches of various sizes, but YMMV.